# Group by demands us to include all selected rows, when we need the results grouped by just one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following this programming exercise: [SQL with Street Fighter](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ac698cdd325ad18a3000170), which statement is:

> It's time to assess which of the world's greatest fighters are through
>   to the 6 coveted places in the semi-finals of the Street Fighter World
>   Fighting Championship. Every fight of the year has been recorded and
>   each fighter's wins and losses need to be added up.
>
> Each row of the table fighters records, alongside the fighter's name,
>   whether they won (1) or lost (0), as well as the type of move that
>   ended the bout.
>
> ```
> id
> name
> won
> lost
> move_id
> ```
>
> winning_moves
>
> ```
> id
> move
> ```
>
> However, due to new health and safety regulations, all ki blasts have
>   been outlawed as a potential fire hazard. Any bout that ended with
>   Hadoken, Shouoken or Kikoken should not be counted in the total wins
>   and losses.
>
> So, your job:
>
> ```
> Return name, won, and lost columns displaying the name, total number of wins and total number of losses. Group by the fighter's
> ```
>
> name.
>       Do not count any wins or losses where the winning move was Hadoken, Shouoken or Kikoken.
>       Order from most-wins to least
>       Return the top 6. Don't worry about ties.

How could we group the fighters by their names?

We have tried:

```
select name, won, lost from fighters inner join winning_moves on fighters.id=winning_moves.id
```

group by name order by won desc limit 6;

However it displays:

There was an error with the SQL query:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "fighters.won" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 3: select
>   name, won, lost from fighters inner join winning_move...

In addition we have also tried to include all selected rows:

```
select name, won, lost from fighters inner join winning_moves on fighters.id=winning_moves.id
group by name,won,lost order by won desc limit 6;
```

But the results differ from the expected.

Expected:

```
name    won lost
Sakura  44  15
Cammy   44  17
Rose    42  19
Karin   42  13
Dhalsim 40  15
Ryu 39  16
```

Actual:

```
name    won lost
Vega    2   1
Guile   2   1
Ryu 2   1
Rose    1   0
Vega    1   0
Zangief 1   0
```

Besides we have read:

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
- [MySql Inner Join with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364602/mysql-inner-join-with-where-clause)
- [How to limit rows in PostgreSQL SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133944/how-to-limit-rows-in-postgresql-select)
- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
- [GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373747/group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)
- [PostgreSQL column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function when using case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368435/postgresql-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate)
- [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

Comment: Always remember to keep your query as short n compact as possible in order to receive its solution in short time

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to have sum() to aggregate the ids wins n loss. In addition to that you dont need join as you dont wanna show the move in the first query

```
     select name, sum(won) as wins, 
     sum(lost) 
     from fighters 
    group by name order by sum(won) 
   desc limit 6;
```